# Setting up Flash CS4 to use Adobe AIR 2.6

Tags: air, flash-cs4, flashdevelop

I use **FlashDevelop as my code editor** and the **Flash CS4 IDE for publishing my AIR files** (as well as asset control, animation creation etc...). The bonus of this is the Flash IDE handles all the crap of creating certificates and whatnot very easily as well.

**Flash CS4 uses Adobe AIR 1.5, which is very old and I am wanting to update it to AIR 2.6**, which as of current writing, is the latest version of AIR. Also, I don't know if this is of any significance, but I would like to publish AIR apps for Android now. I've successfully made an AIR app for PC in the past, using AIR 1.5.

I downloaded the AIR 2.6 SDK from the Adobe website and replaced all the files inside the "AIK1.5" folder of my Flash installation (the folder being still named 1.5 inherently annoys me).

Is there any other steps I must take? Because I'm not convinced I'm publishing AIR 2.6 apps as the `application.xml` file in my AIR project still reads:

```
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/1.5">
```

If I change the version in the .xml, Flash explodes (doesn't compile, gives me an error).

Furthermore, if I go File > Publish Settings, then the Flash tab, the player field reads as "Adobe AIR 1.5". Is this right? I'm assuming this will always be this way, even if you do successfully update the AIR version, since apparently Adobe is too lazy to update CS4 so that it can logically figure out it has the new version of AIR.

Also, if AIR is free, why the hell does Adobe not at the very least, release updates to CS4 that update the version of AIR it uses. This seems to be fully within their power, and it seems incredibly negligent that they don't do this for people who have bought their software.

Please, if you could provide clear step by step help, because I'm very ignorant when it comes to development configurations and stuff. I just want to write code and be off.

**UPDATE**

Once you've updated Flash's AIR library with AIR 2.6, and have compiled your AIR project, **make sure you use the new application descriptor template** from the AIR SDK. I originally thought it just required changing the version number from 1.5 to 2.6 or whatever new version you're using. As seen below.

```
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/1.5">
```

But the format as changed, and you really need to use the new template, otherwise it won't work. And when you compile you won't automatically get a preview of your compiled .swf. This will happen in FlashDevelop too if you've set-up your descriptor file incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bzzzzzzt wrong you can hack apart your CS IDE and get it working follow the concepts in this tutorial, they should get you going and you should be able to piece it together from there.

http://swfhead.com/blog/?p=16

If you have any problems just post a comment I'll help you sort it.

Comment: Haha, was waiting for a reply like this. I thought Mark Redman was wrong (at least, I hope he is), as I've read in a couple of places that it is possible with Flash CS4. I'll check out the link and give it a try, thanks. I will revert once it is done (if I was successful or not). Also, thanks for the offer of helping me along if I experience trouble.

Comment: Cool just let me know I can always help if you run into problems. You can pretty much do anything. For example, I've written a custom standalone flash player for the new flash player 11 so I can publish and test flash player 11 content right inside of my flash IDE just like you normally can (the molehill stuff). It may be useful nfo here so heres a link to my blog: http://blog.ascensionsystems.ca/. Just scroll down 2 or 3 posts you'll see several entries about it.

Comment: I should clarify I wrote a standalone executable that acts as a wrapper to the flash player 11 beta OCX control. Not some magician here that wrote his own flash player overnight lol.

Comment: Last one, in particular this post has links that explains how to update Flash CS5 to be able to publish to flash player 11. You would employ the exact same methods to do what you want to do here: http://blog.ascensionsystems.ca/?p=147

Comment: Hmm, that swfhead link was somewhat helpful but quite badly written, where there are skips in thought and you have to guess where the writer expects you to be. But either way, I followed all the steps, and it did allow me to make his specific example work, for AIR 1.5.2, but if I change the descriptor file to 2.6, Flash doesn't even compile at all.

Comment: There may be limitations actually within the Flash IDE regarding things like the iphone or AIR for android compiler(s) because they're actually quite complex frameworks that use a completely different actionscript compiler. They actually use the LLVM compiler + an updated proprietary version of the actionscript compiler so there are most likely special compilation instructions built in to the IDE. I didn't think of that at first :(. Anyway props to you tho for trying to do things legitimately instead of pirating. Remember you can always use FlashDevelop for your AIR 2.** coding.

Comment: (extension to previous comment) and then just use the Flash CS4 IDE to link to the document class etc. You might be able to integrate with the Flex SDK and do some hackery to still get it to compile.

Comment: Hey, on that note of using FlashDevelop. When I had trouble using the Flash IDE to compile properly, I then tried to make FlashDevelop my full development environment for AIR 2.6+ coding. In that process, also struggling to get it to compile, I had success and figured out what the problem was. And then, I was able to come back and make the Flash IDE behave properly too. Long story short :P After following the instructions to update Flash's AIR library and compiling your project, make sure you USE THE NEW APPLICATION DESCRIPTOR TEMPLATE XML file. And then it will work.

Comment: Really? Awesome man glad you got it working that's sweet. You should do a complete tutorial on your blog and link back to it from this page :).

Comment: Yeah, I totally will, probably in the new week. Should be helpful to others like me. Also, thanks A BUNCH for your help. You've been awesome.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to purchase the latest version of Creative Suite or Flash/Flash Builder to take advance of the latest versions of AIR.

Like any other software, releases are versioned with specific features and newer versions support newer features and integration into other newer technologies.

Its like Microsoft is well in their power to provide docx support in windows 2003, but that would just cause compatibilty, support and licensing issues.

Answer (score 0):

**These are the tutorial for Flash cs 5:**

http://blog.prevail.co.nz/2011/06/21/overlaying-air2-7-in-flash-cs5/

**These are the tutorial for Flash cs 5.5:**

http://www.yeahbutisitflash.com/?p=2949

http://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/multi/overlay-air-sdk-flash-professional.html

**This is the tutorial for Flash cs 6:**

http://www.leebrimelow.com/?p=3335

Comment: These links are sufficient enough to overlay any Air SDK in any version of Flash.